# Distribution of a random summand conditional on the sum of independent identically distributed copies

Tags: random-walks

The question is simple to state:

Let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, where $X_i$ are independent random variables with a common distribution $F$. For simplicity, assume that $X_i \geq 0$ with prob. 1, and that $F$ is absolutely continuous. (Think of $S_n$ as a random walk).

For a fixed $N$, what can we say about the distribution of $X_1$ (or $X_i, i = 1, 2, \cdots$ in general) given an observed value of $S_N$?

In words, if we observe the location of the random walk $S$ after $N$ steps, what does this tell us about the conditional distribution of the summands $X_1, \cdots, X_N$?

I am aware of the well known connection between partial sums of Exponential random variables and Uniform order statistics.

I'm wondering what is known in general.

Comment: In the case that $F$ is a normal distribution, $X_1$ subject to sum $S$ is normal with mean $S/n$ and variance a bit less than the variance of $F$. Presumably other nice distributions also have nice answers. In general, it is not even true that the variance of the components decreases when conditioning on the sum.

Comment: Suppose $X_n$ is bounded above by $x$. Then the conditional probability of $X_n\leq x$ is 1, but $P(X_1+\cdots+X_{n-1}\geq S-x)$ can be anything.

Comment: @VarunVejalla  I couldn't save my previous comment with a ping to you, trying again.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay You're right. I've deleted my earlier comment.

Comment: For some conditional limit theorems see https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-applied-probability/article/conditional-limit-theorems-for-the-terms-of-a-random-walk-revisited/7D4D2F54BEFF0FD44C437EEA3B4AD6D6

Comment: @esg Thank you!! The question arose from the need to describe the joint distribution of jump sizes $J_i$ of a compound Poisson process $P_t = \sum_{i = 1}^{N_t} J_i$ conditioned the value of $P_T$, fixed $T$. ($N_t$ is the Poisson counter). 

Also if interest is the joint distribution of the jumps conditioned on $P_T$ and $N_t$.